# How do I listen to touches/swipes inside an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, touch

I am using a library which adds an iframe on my site.

I would like to record the touches/swipes within the iframe, but ngClick does not work (as the iframe element is not visible until 'runtime').

I have created a directive which records the touch, and would like to add it to the iframe element. I cannot get this to work, however.

What would the best method be to accomplish touch handling inside iframe?

Thanks

Comment: Very vague question. Please share some of what you've done. Maybe some pseudo-code.

Comment: I updated the question to be more precise about touches within iframes. thanks!

Comment: If you control the content of the iframe, try https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer.